# How can my process detect if the computer is shutting down?

Tags: linux, amazon-ec2, shutdown

I'm running some applications on EC2 spot instances. Such instances can be killed by Amazon with no notice.

In the shutdown process, processes are killed in some order.  We have monitoring/recovery programs that should behave differently based on whether the server is shutting down or the process just crashed. (specifically we don't want to do anything if the server is actually shutting down)

How can I detect in the recovery process (if it is still alive) that processes were killed because of a shutdown?

(More system details: I'm running unknown/untrusted/etc code in a sandbox that doesn't modify external state. Generally if sandboxed code crashes, it is fault of author of the untrusted code and we will not rerun it.  But if the sandboxed code is terminated due to the VM shuting down or failing, we need to rerun it on another instance.  The problem I'm having right now is that the user's code is terminated first so the monitoring program incorrectly believes the crash is user error.)

Comment: How does the monitoring process work? What language are user processes written in? Are user processes started and stopped via init scripts, and do you have control over those scripts? I have a few ideas for how to solve this, but it's hard to say what will work without more detail.

Comment: Monitoring is done via waitpid. User process is in python but it could run arbitrary extension modules written in any language. User processes are launched by the same process that handles monitoring (we do not use init scripts).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### agent

Run an agent on each machine that spawns sandbox child-processes. The agent runs your code that is "crash proof", and the sandbox code runs user code which could crash.

The monitoring system that is in charge of starting a new machine with a new sandbox process checks which processes have been killed (both the agent and sandbox process or only the sandbox child process).

It does that by opening a TCP connection (RMI/RPC/HTTP) to the agent querying about its child processes.
If the agent responds - the machine is still running, and it can be asked about its child sandbox processes.
If the agent does not respond - the machine is suspect of being terminated.

### agent (variation)

The agent is also in charge of restarting the child sandbox process on the same VM in case it crashes.

### lookup service

Use a look-up service (such as Zoo Keeper) to keep track of which processes sent heartbeat keep-alive. If the agent is alive then the machine is still running, if the agent is not alive, then it is not running.

### ec2 api

Poll the EC2 APIs to determine if the machine is in running or terminated state.

Comment: Side note:
In Cloudify we use a combination of methods (agent+lookup service) successfully. It is can also detect 100% CPU or Java GC of the sandbox which results in keep-alive not being sent from the sandbox, but the agent reporting the sandbox is running. I plan to add (ec2 api) in order to detect scenarios in which user code requests operating system restart (usually happens on windows machines during installation of legacy components)

Comment: Good thoughts. I'll look into using the local ec2 api to query things.   In terms of the agent, at first glance, this has the same problems as I currently have.  During a shutdown, the sandbox child might be killed before the agent, leading to incorrect beliefs about the child crashing.  Is there a timing guarantee on how long everything must be killed by?

Comment: First you can use the init.d thingy to register daemon shutdown hooks that will take down only the agent which in turn will take down its child processes in orderly fashion. 

Second if you are using a lookup service and the process gets the KILL signal, then the process has time to notify the lookup service it is going down so the lookup service does not need to wait for the keep alive renewal timeout.

Third, even if there aren't any shutdown hooks, by the time the management detects the child has not renewed the keep alive lease, and it tries to contact the agent, the agent is down.

Comment: Thanks for the help. A mix of init.d, ec2 api and waitpid described by LnxPrgr3 should allow me to pull this off.

Answer (score 2):

How does your recovery process work?

If you're using [`waitpid`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/wait.html) to monitor the process, when it exits you can determine:

- Whether it exited normally, and what status the process returned if it did, or
- Whether it exited due to a signal, and what that signal was.

Depending on how the process is shut down, I'd expect to see it either exit normally or exit via `SIGTERM` or `SIGKILL`. `SIGILL`, `SIGABRT`, `SIGFPE`, `SIGBUS`, `SIGSEGV`, and `SIGSYS` would indicate a crash from a programming error.

Comment: We use waitpid. The question is what signal means (and only means) machine is shutting down.  A programming error could also cause SIGTERM or SIGKILL. (calling sys.exit() in your code is considered an 'error' in our system)

Comment: Calling `sys.exit()` should result in a normal exit (`WIFEXITED` should return true), whereas death by system shutdown would be `SIGTERM` and/or `SIGKILL`. Can you use that to tell them apart?

Comment: I cannot, since the programmer may have done a sys.exit(1) for all I know.  I was hoping there was something set in /proc or elsewhere that I could use to tell that the system is in a shutting down state.

Comment: @UsAaR33: A program that does something invalid and is therefore killed by the OS won't have been killed by SIGTERM or SIGKILL.  Calling `sys.exit(...)` will cause the process to exit gracefully (unless some atexit/object destruction code does something invalid), so `WIFSIGNALED` will be false.  If a process has exited due to SIGTERM/SIGKILL, that means something chose to kill it and in your described situation, that would most likely be due to system shutdown.

Comment: @jamessan My bad, you are correct in that this method will correctly detect if another program (e.g. shutdown process) terminated the user's process.  It is almost perfect and I may in fact use it partially... the one downside is the programmer could (for some reason) kill his own process with signals, conflating this test.

Answer (score 1):

That sounds like a very fragile scheme.  Don't try to detect the state of the system: have your application write out a validity token (and sync the relevant files!) somehow following a "clean" shutdown/halt/stop of the app and use that.

Comment: For a general application that would work.  However, the application we monitor is written by other users and can crash due to that user's fault. Indeed, if it crashes, it is almost guaranteed due to some problem with that user's code, with the exception of our hardware shutting down.

Comment: Then I think you need to add more detail to the question.  From that response, I gather that you're trying to run untrusted/untested/unvalidated code and get it to restore cleanly after a failure.  I don't see how that's possible.

Comment: Correct, I'm running unknown/untrust/etc code in a sandbox.  One requirement is that code doesn't modify external state.  Which means if the machine fails, it is possible to restart on another machine. However, if code crashes for other reasons, we assume it is fault of code author and don't restart.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that when the instance is shutting down your monitoring process would receive a SIGTERM signal.

So would it be possible to do something like - IF monitored process has exited && no SIGTERM signal received within next say 5 seconds - assume the process crashed. If a SIGTERM was received, simply exit from the signal handler.